# When would correlation between two variables not exist?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, variance, covariance, moments

If we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, then $\text{corr}(X,Y)=\dfrac{
\text{cov}(X,Y)
}{
\sqrt{
\text{var}(X)\text{var}(Y)
}
}$.

This correlation will not be defined if either variable has an undefined variance.

Is it possible for the variables to have an undefined covariance while having defined variance? Can anything else go awry to keep the correlation from being defined?

Comment: Zero variance for either would make this $\frac00$, but positive finite variance for both would ensure a covariance with $0 \le \text{cov}(X,Y)^2 \le \text{var}(X)\text{var}(Y)$ and so a correlation with $-1 \le  \text{corr}(X,Y)\le1$

Comment: Won't the existence of two variances imply the existence of covariance by CS Inequality?

Comment: What does "undefined" mean precisely? There is a clear problem if either variance is 0, which happens when either variable is constant, but there is nothing undefined about zero. It's just a logical and inevitable result of the rules. As for the question: zero covariance can arise if either variable is a constant or in other circumstances, but I can't think of any sense in which the covariance is undefined, unless missing values are the culprit (or in some cases depending on code with a sample size of 1).

Comment: @NickCox I suspect "undefined variance" means something like either infinite variance or no finite mean to use in the calculation of variance.  Similarly with "undefined covariance"

Comment: @Henry I've never seen infinite variance in a dataset, but more seriously your comment raises the counter-question of whether Dave means: in principle? in practice? or both?

Comment: @NickCox The question talks about random variables rather than samples, so may include probability distributions with very heavy tails

Comment: To be fair to Nick, I edited in “random” variable to clarify after his comments. Yes, I mean for theoretical random variables that could be Cauchy and not even have a first moment, not empirical correlation/variance/covariance.

Comment: I am relieved to find that I did not miss that!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: That is what @User1865345 meant by CS. FWIW, it is Schwarz not Schwartz. That mistake gets a black mark in my book.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on CS talks about variance and covariance. Irritatingly, however, it does not address why the variance existing implies that covariance must exist. Does that drop out of the fact that we have some vector space of distributions with the inner product defined by an expected value? (That doesn’t make sense, now that I’ve typed it. Cauchy distributions are distributions, too!)

Comment: Check Michael Hardy's [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/804256/1074816) @Dave.